# Raspberry Pi + Bluez + A2DP + AVRCP

Tags: raspberry-pi, dbus, a2dp, avrcp, mediaplayback

In the past 2 days i've been googling for a way to control the media playback from my iPhone through my Raspiberry pi headless speaker.

I've successfully setup the pi using the following tutorial: 
[Headless A2DP Audio Streaming on Raspbian Stretch](https://gist.github.com/mill1000/74c7473ee3b4a5b13f6325e9994ff84c) 
and now i'm looking for a way to control the playback of the audio stream from my raspberry pi.

I've been looking into MediaTransport1, MediaPlayer1, MediaControl1 but unfortunately i wasn't successful.

to give you a few examples of the trial and error I've performed:

for:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Pause
```

i received:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Pause" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaPlayer1" doesn't exist
```

for

```
qdbus --system org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/fd0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.bluez.MediaTransport1 Volume 127
```

i received

```
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidSignature
Invalid signature for 'Volume'
```

Additionally, i've found a player that i thought i could use to build my own script as an example  [Here](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/test/simple-player) but i've got an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/blueutils $ python simpleplayer.py


Available commands:
        PropertiesChanged(interface, properties)
        help(cmd)

Use python syntax to pass arguments to available methods.
E.g.: PropertiesChanged({'Metadata' : {'Title': 'My title',             'Album': 'my album' }})

>>> <Interface <ProxyObject wrapping <dbus._dbus.SystemBus (system) at 0xb61968d0> :1.13 /org/bluez/hci0 at 0xb619db70> implementing 'org.bluez.Media1' at 0xb619dc50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpleplayer.py", line 197, in <module>
    media.RegisterPlayer(dbus.ObjectPath(path), player.properties)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NotSupported: Operation is not supported
```

when i do an introspect

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

i get his:

```
<node>
    <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
        <method name="Introspect">
            <arg name="xml" type="s" direction="out"/>
        </method>
    </interface>
    <interface name="org.bluez.Adapter1">
        <method name="StartDiscovery"></method>
        <method name="SetDiscoveryFilter">
            <arg name="properties" type="a{sv}" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="StopDiscovery"></method>
        <method name="RemoveDevice">
            <arg name="device" type="o" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <property name="Address" type="s" access="read"></property>
        <property name="Name" type="s" access="read"></property>
        <property name="Alias" type="s" access="readwrite"></property>
        <property name="Class" type="u" access="read"></property>
        <property name="Powered" type="b" access="readwrite"></property>
        <property name="Discoverable" type="b" access="readwrite"></property>
        <property name="DiscoverableTimeout" type="u" access="readwrite"></property>]

        <property name="Pairable" type="b" access="readwrite"></property>
        <property name="PairableTimeout" type="u" access="readwrite"></property>
        <property name="Discovering" type="b" access="read"></property>
        <property name="UUIDs" type="as" access="read"></property>
        <property name="Modalias" type="s" access="read"></property>
    </interface>
    <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
        <method name="Get">
            <arg name="interface" type="s" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="name" type="s" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="value" type="v" direction="out"/>
        </method>
        <method name="Set">
            <arg name="interface" type="s" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="name" type="s" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="value" type="v" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="GetAll">
            <arg name="interface" type="s" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="properties" type="a{sv}" direction="out"/>
        </method>
        <signal name="PropertiesChanged">
            <arg name="interface" type="s"/>
            <arg name="changed_properties" type="a{sv}"/>
            <arg name="invalidated_properties" type="as"/>
        </signal>
    </interface>
    <interface name="org.bluez.GattManager1">
        <method name="RegisterApplication">
            <arg name="application" type="o" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="options" type="a{sv}" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="UnregisterApplication">
            <arg name="application" type="o" direction="in"/>
        </method>
    </interface>
    <interface name="org.bluez.Media1">
        <method name="RegisterEndpoint">
            <arg name="endpoint" type="o" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="properties" type="a{sv}" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="UnregisterEndpoint">
            <arg name="endpoint" type="o" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="RegisterPlayer">
            <arg name="player" type="o" direction="in"/>
            <arg name="properties" type="a{sv}" direction="in"/>
        </method>
        <method name="UnregisterPlayer">
            <arg name="player" type="o" direction="in"/>
        </method>
    </interface>
    <node name="dev_40_9C_28_07_63_DD"/>
    <node name="dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B"/>
</node>
```

Can anybody help me figure this issue out, or does anybody know a procedure to control the playback of the music on the phone, using the raspberry pi ?

Regards.

Update 1: 
Thank you so much @Parthiban for it works perfectly.

Additionally, i have to say that i reinstalled the bluez version to 5.50 by following the tutorial here: [Install bluez on the Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation) as i wasn't able to see /playerX (0 in my case). Before i compiled the sources, i did a little extra (not sure it's relevant but it doesn't hurt), i added the `.auto_connect   = true`

the the avrcp profiles as indicated :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28914592/1421040)

hope this helps everybody that may face my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the signature to set the volume as below,

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest='org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/fd0' org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:"org.bluez.MediaTransport1" string:"Volume" variant:uint16:127
```

This is because, as mentioned in [dbus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties) you need to specify three arguments when using set,

1. Interface Name
2. Property Name
3. Property value as variant

For the pause method, explore the "`org.bluez.MediaPlayer1`" interface of your device using "`org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect`". The object path which you have used to access the method "Pause" is wrong. As stated [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/media-api.txt#n128), you need to use "`[variable prefix]/{hci0,hci1,...}/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/playerX`".

So in your case, it should be,

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest='org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/playerX' org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Pause
```

Where playerX needs to be replaced by your device player (you can get that from Introspect or watch on "InterfaceAdded" Signal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the Pause command works find, however when i try to set volume level, i get the following error :  `dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest='org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/fd0' org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:"org.bluez.MediaTransport1" string:"Volume" uint16:127'  '
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Set" with signature "ssq" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist`

Comment: @ady_e_n: Am not sure why "Set" method is unavailable here. Check "Introspect" in object path "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/fd0". If not present, then try to use "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B". I am not sure about the hierarchy how MediaTransport interfaces are organized.

Comment: i've done this:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/jdgh6RiLTVQNNRR98 the method seams to be there: `</method><method name="Set"><arg name="interface" type="s" direction="in"/>
<arg name="name" type="s" direction="in"/>
<arg name="value" type="v" direction="in"/>
` it just returns an error

Comment: @ady_e_n: Got it: Try this `dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest='org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_85_50_B1_C8_6B/fd0' org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:"org.bluez.MediaTransport1" string:"Volume" variant:uint16:127`

Comment: @ady_e_n: Updated in answer for any future reference!